# Block users from REST API endpoint while still grabbing data from it

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I have created 2 REST API endpoint to store the CPT data and their custom fields:

**Archive Data**: `xyz.com/wp-json/wl/v2/businesses`
**Single Business data**: `xyz.com/wp-json/wl/v2/businesses/<ID>`

Both these endpoints have been registered with the permission callbacks;

```
register_rest_route( 'wl/v2', '/businesses', array(
    'methods'   => WP_REST_Server::READABLE,
    'callback'  =>  'wl_businesses_posts',
    'permission_callback'   => '__return_true'
));
```

It is a business directory website where a common dashboard ( `xyz.com/dashboard` ) for each 'business' client exists and this dashboard page pulls in data for that 'business' from the *Single Business data* REST API endpoint above and fills the input fields on the page.

There is also another page accessible to the non-logged in visitors( `xyz.com/business1` ) that is common  for all businesses and is a read-only page where visitors can check that business' details. This page too pulls data from the *Single Business data* REST API endpoint mentioned above.

What I am trying to accomplish is that no one except the Admin should be able to peep into the **Archive Data** or the **Single Business data** endpoints directly which displays that tall JSON data, to avoid stealing info of all the businesses registered with the site. But at the same time, I would want these endpoints to be accessible by the `wp_remote_retrieve_body( wp_remote_get( $url ) );`code to populate the **dashboard** and **single business info** pages.

I tried this code but it obviously also blocks the requests made by the page code to pull and populate data in the pages.

```
add_filter( 'rest_authentication_errors', function( $result ) {
    if ( ! empty( $result ) ) {
      return $result;
    }
    if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
      return new WP_Error( 'rest_not_logged_in', 'You are not currently logged in.', array( 'status' => 401 ) );
    }
    return $result;
  });
```

I am not necessarily looking for a code, just the direction about how to solve this problem.

**------------------------------UPDATE----------------------------
:**
Like I said, since it is a business directory, even non logged-in users should see the archive pages and single business pages of the CPT. I've learned recently about the 'permission callbacks' in `register_rest_route`  arguments, so how would I pass a custom 'key' argument in the wp_remote_get function and receive and validate it in the permission callback?

Comment: Use a JWT token that contains something identifying an admin and send it with a bearer authorization header from client to server each time you do an http request.

Comment: You may also need to change your permission callback and have it check whether the current user has admin capabilities (eg. `current_user_can('manage_options');`).

Comment: @cabrerahector That is the exact approach I am planning to take. But like I said, I since it is a business directory, even non logged in users should see the archive pages and single business pages of the CPT. I've learnedrecently about the permission callbacks, so how would I pass a custom 'key' argument in the `wp_remote_get` function and receive and validate it in the permission callback?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I've managed to secure my endpoint by passing a param in the request, and only if it matches in the permission callback of the rest endpoint, then the data is retrieved:

```
$userData = wp_remote_retrieve_body( wp_remote_get( $url,  array(
        'body' => array(
            'param' => '1'
        ),
        'sslverify' => false,
    )  ) );
```

And in the `register_rest_route`:

```
'permission_callback'   => function( WP_REST_Request $request ) {
            if ( '1' == $request->get_param( 'param' ) ) {
           return true;
         } else {
       return false;
    }
 }
```

I'm so happy I wont have to use a plugin for this :D